# CSS how to make <TD> a fixed height?

Tags: html, css

```
<table  cellspacing="0" id="contactTable" style="table-layout:table-layout:fixed;; width:100%; font-weight:normal; position: absolute; top:45; left: 0;">

<td height="50" style="padding-left:5px; overflow:hidden; ">
    <span style="text-transform:capitalize;line-height:100%;">
    //names here
    </span>                          
    </td>

...more code
</table>
```

This doesn't work. Overflow is still making the cell taller, height is addapting to content.

Comment: @Šime Vidas yes. i just didnt paste it here

Comment: Make an example on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), and make sure your example has the same problem you're describing in your question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The best solution is to put a div inside the cell with the height:

```
<td style="padding-left:5px;">
  <div style="height: 50px; overflow:hidden;">
      ...
  </div>
</td>
```

BTW, what is the span for? If you only need it for styling, you can style the cell directly instead.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS property you are looking for is `line-height`. You simply have to put it in the `<td>`, not in the contained `<span>`

```
<td style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 50px; overflow: hidden">
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing table rows

---

```
<table  cellspacing="0" id="contactTable" style="table-layout:fixed; width:100%; font-weight:normal; position: absolute; top:45; left: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:5px; overflow:hidden; height: 50px;">
            <span style="text-transform:capitalize;line-height:100%;">
               //names here
            </span>                          
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am just learning web designing so am I kind of a noob. As I was also facing this problem and some of the solution I can't understand at my level. While I was trying I found that the height of the cell auto adjusted by the content of the `<td>` element. So what I did was I put a `<div>` element inside the `<td>` and fixed it's height. No no matter how the content is, the height of the `<td>` is fixed in a way.

```
<td class="center">
<div class="align">
.
.
.

</div>
</td>


.align{  height: 200px;
     overflow:scroll;
     width:600px;
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything useful to [RoToRa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091247/1016716) from 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. You can use the span directly. It's the best approach. The TD/TR dont respect the height set.
Just put a class on your span and add the css or just aply it directly with the style atribute.

```
<span class"MyClass">LONG NAME</span>

.MyClass { //on CSS File
    height: 60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

or just

```
<span style="height: 60px; overflow:hidden;">LONG NAME</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the css height on the td rather than the html attribute?

```
<td style="padding-left:5px; height:50px; overflow:hidden; ">
    <span style="text-transform:capitalize;line-height:100%;">    //names here
    </span>
```

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work. the cell still gets taller if there is a lot of text

Answer (score 0):

Go with Div inside the td and using the css show the dots for overflow

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
}

.clampMe {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.clampMe:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="box">
        <div class="clampMe">
          FASTag is a simple to use, reloadable tag which enables automatic deduction of toll charges and lets you pass through the toll plaza without stopping for the cash transaction. FASTag is linked to a prepaid account from which the applicable toll amount
          is deducted. The tag employs Radio-frequency Identification (RFID) technology and is affixed on the vehicle's windscreen after the tag account is active.
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>testasdfasdfasd asdf asdf asdfas dffasdf asd</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.yourClass {padding: 1pt 0 1pt 0;}
```

and adjust the "1pt" values (top & bottom) for the required height.

For some reason

```
padding 0;
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score -6):

I would have written

```
<td style="height:50px">
...
</td>
```