# DIV must always define display and position or not or what is default

Tags: html, css, sass

After searching a lot I cannot find the answer I am looking for. I am a TABLE user currently editing my old site to new tech but I have a question:

```
    <div style="background:#6666; 
here: we go; 
display:block; position:relative;> test </div>
```

Does I must set always to all divs the display and position attributes ?

If I don't set default attributes what will then be their default attributes for display and position?

Yeah it is a nice question, many tell you how to use those attributes but nobody tell you if you have to or not...

Any div guy

Comment: Out of my own curiosity, what is the `here: we go;` style supposed to be?

Comment: This is just to separate or initiate the question, in other words it is nothing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browsers' default CSS for HTML elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements)

Comment: sdcr go fu-- yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not required.  If you don't specify them, `div` tags will have the following default values for those CSS properties:

```
display: block
position: static
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex. Just a small question: If I set a table TD height in css will it work or I must insert a DIV inside the TD to make it be the height I want tit to be?

Comment: I will set your question as correct in 5 minutes when system let me do it

Comment: [Use a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height).

Comment: So you are breaking with tables you say in your question and now you are crawling back to them?? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Mikey I must have a table for tubular data only