# Why does the table cell height increases when i place a button in a column? How can i avoid that?

Tags: html, css

```
.edit-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.edit-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.edit-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
    background-color: white;
}
```

This is my table CSS which works fine. But when i place a edit button in the last column the size of all the cells increases. How can i avoid that?

Html Code:

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;height:440px;width:100%;overflow:auto;overflow-x: hidden">
    <table  align="center" width="100%" class="zui-table">


        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>abc</th>
                <th>cvb</th>
                <th>bnm</th>
                <th>hju</th>
                <th>juik</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>

            <c:forEach items="${request.List}" var="emp">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.userid}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.firstname}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.rolelist}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${emp.countrycodelist}"></c:out></td>
                    <%-- <td><c:out value="${'<input type="submit" name="${emp.userid}" value="Edit" />'}"></c:out></td> --%>
                     <td><form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit" method="post" >
                             <input type="submit" name="${emp.userid}"  value="Edit" />
                             <input type="hidden" value="${emp.userid}" name="userid" />
                        </form></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
     </div>
```

Here is the Html Code. Tried height in tr and td but both did not work.

Comment: add your html code

Comment: @LaljiTadhani : added html code.

Comment: Found an answer here. Adding div works fine. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height)

Answer (score 0):

Best option will be to use line-height in td.

Comment: line-height is not giving appropriate result.

Answer (score 0):

change the button style

```
input[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Only the button size is changing. The cell size remains big.