# How to fix large amount of content into table cell without stretching entire table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am trying to fit a lot of text to my **HTML table**:

```
 <tr>
   <td>
     - some information 1
     - anotothe information 1
     - some information 2
     - some information 3
     - some information 4
     - some information 5
     - some information 6
     - some information 7
     - some information 8
     - some information 9
     - some information 10
     - some information 11
     - some information 12
     - some information 13
     - some information 14
     - ...
  </td>
  <td>
      ...
  </td>
</tr>
```

All the other **rows** are standard height. This has so much content, it makes the table cell too tall and pushes the others off the screen.

Can you advise on some simple CSS or JS trick how to solve this issue?

I am thinking about some kind of JS code - so when you hover about this **table cell** this content would roll on the screen and we could read it easily?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for suggestions on how to implement your idea. You have to first try it and if it doesn't work, we can help you fix it if you explain what you have tried and what is not working along with the code in question

Comment: I have always had a very pleasant experience with Stack Overflow. This is a regular question as thousands of others. People come here and ask - if someone is kind enough then - he or she answers. I am very disappointed  with this reaction. If you do not want to answer- why even comment ?

Comment: how should that row behave setting its height ? should it be a max-height or should the height be according to the content of sibbling cells ?

Comment: @user2156115 Because your question will elicit lots of suggestions and there won't be a correct answer. This is bullet 4 on what's off-topic for SO: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam_. **Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it** See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery with it's simple show and hide methods, but in vanilla JS you could try something like this:

```
<td onmouseenter="expandContent()" onmouseleave="hideContent()">
    <div class="hoverable" onmouseenter="expandContent()" onmouseleave="hideContent()">
     ...content
    </div>
</td>

function expandContent(){
    const content = document.querySelector(".hoverable");
    content.style.height = "300px"; //or whatever height u need to fit the content, can be set to auto too. 
}

 function hideContent(){
    const content = document.querySelector(".hoverable");
    content.style.height = "100px"; //or whatever inital height u want to have
}
```

and for your CSS:

```
.hoverable{
    height: 100px; //your initial height
    overflow: hidden; //stop content from "spilling" 
} 
td{ 
    overflow: hidden //stop content from "spilling"
}
```

It should expand your td on hover to the height you want. Let me know if it works for you :)

EDIT: I clearly went too far yesterday. **Simplest solution** to this problem, I believe, is adding :hover property to css.

```
.hoverable{
    height: 5px; //your initial height 
    overflow: hidden; //stop content from "spilling"
}
.hoverable:hover {
    height: 600px; //or height: auto then it will expand to text height
}
td{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That should be everything you need, no additional JavaScript methods. You can also add other properties on hover like for example changing background color

```
background: lightblue;
```

Sorry for confusion :)

Comment: I have tried something like this but it does not work
https://gist.github.com/xjantoth/8e30d00cd430b54891f35e90b271fd5b

Comment: Sorry I didn't write it properly - it should be function expandContent(){..} and function hideContent(){...} I've edited the original code to reflect that. Now it will work :)

Comment: Well thanks it works - the only problem is that even though I set up hight to 5px -  the minimum windows size is not going to be this 5px - it basically accommodates to min text I put in - so if I input a lot of text - this cell is initially still very wide. Can you advise on that ?

Comment: You could use a div inside td I think. for example: <td>
  <div class="hoverable">
      ...content here
  </div>
</td> Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height

Comment: Well indeed <div class=".."> helps but now text is flowing out of the table . I have updated my gist.

Comment: add this to css td{
        overflow: hidden;
    } to make sure it doesnt overflow from td. Plus 5px height will look weird with current table layout so you can set initial div height to 15px

Comment: Thank you so much it works, of course that before asking over here I tried many options - but the solution you have proposed is perfect :) I much appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. You can mark my answer as a solution with 'tick-mark' under upvote button if you want. Have a good day :) I have edited answer to reflect the div nested inside td

Comment: Perhaps I found a quite serious problem 
https://gist.github.com/xjantoth/8e30d00cd430b54891f35e90b271fd5b
It works wery well if I only have one row table :), but once I started adding row - it started messing up. I have updated my gist - if you can tak a look - of course I have tried modifications - but non of them worked.

Comment: Idk where my brain went yesterday. There's SUPER simple solution to your problem. Remove all JS and methods from html. Add this to css: .hoverable:hover {
        height: 600px;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify the question if this answers requires other sizing settings for the table.

If your colls have a fixed width and if the cell to scroll stands aside or in between other cells, you can eventually reset its own display to allow it to scroll.

example:

```css
table {
  width:350px;/* do you have a set width ? */
  border:solid;
}
td {
  width: 175px;/* make it fit your column's width */
  display:block;/* destroy table-layout to allow scrolling */
  max-height:150px;/* set a fixed or a max-height to tell when to start scrolling */
  overflow:auto;/* trigger scrolling when needed */
}
td + td {
  background:yellow; /* see me */
  display:table-cell;/*back to normal , defaut display tor  TD elements */
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
   <td>
     - some information 1
     - anotothe information 1
     - some information 2
     - some information 3
     - some information 4
     - some information 5
     - some information 6
     - some information 7
     - some information 8
     - some information 9
     - some information 10
     - some information 11
     - some information 12
     - some information 13
     - some information 14
     - ...
  </td>
  <td>
      little amount of content here
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give the  a height and then set the overflow to scroll. Like this:

```
td {
    display: block;
    height: 50px; //whatever height you want to limit it to
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: ?? how can you upvote an overflow on a table-cell which cannot show a scrollbar unless you reset display . Did you even check it worked ? https://jsfiddle.net/k27jaxyn/ a table shrinks and expand from its content, width or height are actually behaving like min-widthand min-height. If you reset table-layout to fixed, then you fix the width, **not the height** :)