# How to stop HTML table cells stretching vertically?

Tags: html

When a cell in the table is clicked, an X appears, which it is supposed to do but I am trying to stop the table cell from stretching vertically when this happens. Once every cell in the column has been clicked, the cells revert to normal size but I need it so the cells never change size.

```js
let turn = false;
function play(cell) {
  if (turn == true) {
    cell.innerHTML = 'X';
  } else {
    cell.innerHTML = 'O';
  }

  if (turn == true) {
    turn = false;
  } else {
    turn = true;
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 25px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  display: inline-table;
}

#grid {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please include your JS too so we can see a working example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS how to make <TD> a fixed height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML tables are supposed to stretch and scale to fit the content that's inside by default. This can be overridden by explicitly defining a height and width. So if you add `height: 100px;` to the `td` CSS rule, it will lock in the height of the `td` to 100px;

BUT WAIT this still doesn't completely fix it because the height of an X or O at 100px font-size makes the cell larger than 100px tall. If you inspect this using your browser's Developer Tools, you can see that once a character is added inside a table cell, the cell height is actually 138px (at least in Chrome on Windows, this likely varies slightly on different browsers). To get around that you can set the height in CSS to be slightly higher, say 150px. Another option is to build this using `div`s instead which shouldn't auto-expand when you set an explicit height/width.

Per [CSS how to make <TD> a fixed height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091179/css-how-to-make-td-a-fixed-height) it looks like the most consistent workaround for this is to add `divs` inside the cells with fixed height/width rather than setting these values on the `td`.

```js
let turn = false;

function play(cell) {
  // modified this so you can toggle an empty cell to experiment with heights
  if (cell.innerHTML != '') {
    cell.innerHTML = '';
  } else if (turn) {
    cell.innerHTML = 'X';
  } else {
    cell.innerHTML = 'O';
  }

  turn = !turn;
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 138px; /* add this */
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 25px;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
  display: inline-table;
}

#grid {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)">X</td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
        <td onclick="play(this)"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```